# Xcode 7 record ui button doesn't appear

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

I created a ui test class:

```
import Foundation
import XCTest
@testable import TestProject

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
class ChangeWishListUITests: XCTestCase {

    func testExample() {
        // Use recording to get started writing UI tests.
        // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.


    }

}
```

Run app on iphone 6 simulator with ios 9.3:
[image]

But, record button, like in this tutorial:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/RecordingUITests.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH75-SW1

didn't appear.

[image]

Comment: sometimes you need to press cursor inside testExample() test case, also take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874855/xcode-7-ui-tests-recording-button-is-greyed-out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. your cursor has to be inside the method that you want to implement (because Xcode generates the code to the cursor position)

If this doesn't help:

2. sometimes Xcode appears to be instable when you add a UI test to an existing project. The following sequence helped me in some cases:

   - clean the project
   - restart Xcode
   - rebuild the project
   - click inside the test method to set the cursor

Sometimes I had to do this two times.

3. Your simulator has to run at least iOS 9.0

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had forgotten to add a UI Test target in the project and assign the test file to this target

Answer (score 0):

the debug area is hidden...

toggle debug editor on keyboard by pressing "shift + command + y" simultaneously